# How do we send keystrokes and values in an interactive python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32, pywin

Editor: Eclipse Pydev, OS- Centos

I have a python script which executes an interactive shell script. Half way through the execution, I am prompted for input values. The values to be entered differs. So, for example, if halfway through the script, I might be prompted like this :

Select the port [Default]: --Value to be entered will be `Enter`(enter key)--

Enter the path: --Value to be entered will be `/usr/bin`--

Are you sure? (y/n): --Value to be entered will be `y`--

The sequence of questions will be the same and not dynamic. Is there a separate package that I need to import?

I tried PyUserInput but was unable to import the package in my script.

Comment: have a look at "expect"

Comment: Perhaps you could use `subprocess.communicate`.